# ArrayList, group by, sumBy нескольким полям

Tags: kotlin

Есть такой код на kotlin...

```
class ResultGroup(var userId: Int, var movieRating: List<MovieRating>? = null)

class MovieRating(public var movieTitle: String? = null, var rating: Int? = null)
```

В `ResultGroup` лежат данные не сгруппированные, т.е. пользователь и фильмы (movieTitle) которые он смотрел с количеством просмотров (rating), все нужно сгруппировать по `userId`, `movieTitle`, а `rating` просуммировать.
Делаю что то вроде:

```
val a = resultList.groupBy { {ResultGroup::userId};{MovieRating::movieTitle} }
        .mapValues { it.value.sumBy { it.movieRating........... }  }
```

ну и т.п. и т.д, кажется все уже перепробовал, но компилятор постоянно ругается, уговорить не удается))
Подскажите как в данном случае правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то так, если я правильно понял вопрос

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test


class ResultGroup(val userId: Int, val movieRating: List<MovieRating>)

class MovieRating(val movieTitle: String, val rating: Int)

class Tester {
    @Test
    fun test() {
        val userId1 = 1
        val userId2 = 2
        val movieTitle1 = "film1"
        val movieTitle2 = "film2"


        val resultList: List<ResultGroup> = listOf(
            ResultGroup(
                userId1,
                listOf(MovieRating(movieTitle1, 2), MovieRating(movieTitle2, 2))
            ),
            ResultGroup(
                userId2,
                listOf(MovieRating(movieTitle1, 2))
            ),
            ResultGroup(
                userId1,
                listOf(MovieRating(movieTitle1, 4))
            )


        )

        // Раскываем всё в сплошной лист
        val a = resultList.flatMap { topIt ->
            topIt.movieRating.map { downIt ->
                Triple(topIt.userId, downIt.movieTitle, downIt.rating)
            }
        }
        //Группируем по паре (пользователь, фильм)
        val r = a.groupBy({ Pair(it.first, it.second) }, { it.third })

        //Считаем общее количество просмотров для каждой пары (пользователь, фильм)
        val uniqueList = r.entries.map {
            Triple(it.key.first, it.key.second, it.value.fold(0, { acc, t -> acc + t }))
        }.toList()

        Assertions.assertEquals(6, uniqueList.find { it.first == userId1 && it.second == movieTitle1 }!!.third)
        Assertions.assertEquals(2, uniqueList.find { it.first == userId1 && it.second == movieTitle2 }!!.third)
        Assertions.assertEquals(2, uniqueList.find { it.first == userId2 && it.second == movieTitle1 }!!.third)

    }


}
```

Comment: Верно поняли, спасибо огромное!!! А, то мозг сломал уже(( Вот как до этого додуматься?! Пытался все в строчку....